# Go through each image using jquery .each to add a different id to each image?

Tags: jquery

I need to increment the id for each image such as `"R" + i` so that it becomes R1 R2 etc for each image with title Router.

This is my code:

```
var incr = 1;

var router = $(this).find("img[title='Router']");

if(router.length > 0)
    {
      router.each(function () {
      router.attr('id', 'R' + incr);
      });
     incr++
    }
```

Right now the output is that each image with title Router is changing to the count of the current number of routers. That is, if the count of routers are 3, then for each image with title Router, the ID becomes R3 for each of them.

How can I fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `incr++` inside of loop:

```
var router = $(this).find("img[title='Router']"),
    incr   = 1;

if(router.length > 0){
   router.each(function () {
     router.attr('id', 'R' + incr);
     incr++;
   });
}
```

or even you can use `index` which `each()` provides:

```
var router = $(this).find("img[title='Router']");
if(router.length > 0){
   router.each(function (i) {
     router.attr('id', 'R' + (i+1));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code as

```
var incr = 1;
$("img[title='Router']").each(function() {
 this.attr('id','R'+ incr);
 incr++;
});
```